# Cannot process POST request in Sails.js correctly

Tags: node.js, post, sails.js, sails-mongo

I'm trying to add comments functionality into my Sails.js blog application. However, I don't seem to write my controller action correctly.

When I submit the comment form, the page starts to reload, but does not finish reloading.

Here's my controller code:

```
const gravatar = require('gravatar');

module.exports = {

    blog: (req, res) => {
        Post.find({}).exec((err, posts) => {
            if (err) {
                res.send(500, { error: 'Database Error' });
            }

            res.view('all-posts', { posts });
        });

    },

    singlePost: (req, res) => {
        Post.findOneBySlug(req.params.slug).exec((err, post) => {
            if (err) {
                res.send(500, { error: 'Database Error' });
            }

            res.view('single-post', {
                post,
                gravatar: gravatar.url
            });
        });
    },

addComment: (req, res) => {
    const {
        name, comment, email,
        url, slug,
    } = req.allParams();

    Post.findOneBySlug(slug).exec((err, post) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.send(500, { error: 'Database Error' });

            Comment.create({
                body: comment, name, email, website: url
            }).exec((error, comment) => {
                if (error) {
                    return res.send(500, { error: 'Database Error' });
                }
                console.log(comment);
                post.comments.addComment({slug, comment});
                post.save();

                res.redirect(`/${slug}`);
            });
        }
    });

    return false;
},

};
```

And here's my `routes.js` file:

```
module.exports.routes = {
  'get /blog': 'BlogController.blog',

  'get /:slug': 'BlogController.singlePost',

  'post /:slug/new-comment': 'BlogController.addComment'
};
```

And this is my model `Post.js`

```
module.exports = {

  identity: 'Post',

  attributes: {

    title: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true,
      unique: true
    },

    body: {
      type: 'string'
    },

    categories: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true
    },

    imageUrl: {
      type: 'string'
    },

    comments: {
      collection: 'Comment',
      via: 'post'
    },

    slug: {
      type: 'slug',
      from: 'title',
      blacklist: ['search', 'blog', 'contacts']
    }
  },

  addComment: (options, cb) => {
    Post.findOneBySlug(options.slug).exec((err, post) => {
      if (err) return cb(err);
      if (!post) return cb(new Error('Post not found.'));

      post.comments.add(options.comment);
      post.save(cb);
    })
  },

  connection: 'mongodb'
};
```

---

So, when I submit the comment form on the `/:slug` page, nothing actually happens accept the page tries to reload. And in the database nothing gets saved as well.

The form parameters get sent from the form, so on the client side everything should be fine.

---

How how I approach this post request correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `return` statement before each `res.send(500, ...);` call, because currently, in the case of the error, your code tries to send the response twice, and client doesn't get the response with the actual error:

```
if (err) {
  return res.send(500, { error: 'Database Error' });
}
... rest code
```

I suspect, that the reason why nothing is saved in db is invalid parameters in request body.

Comment: I've updated my `addComment` action (see the updated code in question), but the problem persists.

Comment: You changed code incorrectly. Check my updated answer.

Comment: What do you mean by invalid parameters? Inside `addComment` action the `req.allParams()` object contains all the data I need to save the model.

Comment: Omg, yeah, that was a stupid mistake with the curly brace)

Comment: Why do you think that `req.allParams()` contains all necessary data? Are you sure that body is not empty? In your model, `title` is marked as required for example. And if it's not defined in the body, the data won't be saved.

Comment: Yeah, you were right, the title parameter indeed was undefined. Thanks a lot for your help!